# Create a keyword field concatenated of other fields

Tags: elasticsearch, concatenation, elasticsearch-6

I've got an index with a mapping of 3 fields. Let's say `f1`, `f2` and `f3`.
I want a new keyword field with the **concatenation** of the values of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` to be able to aggregate by it to avoid having lots of nested loops when checking the search results.

I've seen that this could be achieved by **source transformation**, but since elastic v5, this feature was deleted.

ElasticSearch version used: 6.5

**Q: How can I archieve the concatenation in ElasticSearch v 6.5?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was indeed source transformation prior to ES 5, but as of ES 5 there is now a more powerful feature called [ingest nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) which will allow you to easily achieve what you need:

First, define an ingest pipeline using a [`set` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html) that will help you concatenate three fields into one:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/concat
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "field4",
        "value": "{{field1}} {{field2}} {{field3}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then index a document using that pipeline:

```
PUT index/doc/1?pipeline=concat
{
  "field1": "1",
  "field2": "2",
  "field3": "3"
}
```

And the indexed document will look like:

```
{
  "field1": "1",
  "field2": "2",
  "field3": "3",
  "field4": "1 2 3"
}
```

Just make sure to create the index with the appropriate mapping for `field4` prior to indexing the first document.